# node gets wrong internal path - translations

Tags: i18n-l10n, uri

its a bit twisted, but to describe the situation:

whe have a multilingual site but you don't select by language rather by country. (you've for instance BE-FR in your path and not simple fr)
and since there is not a translation for every country, there is also a global english fallback.

now the problem is:
I switch the site language per language dropdown on the frontpage and get redirected to the according frontpage in the other language, but:
on any node link I try then (like further menu items) I only get >>page not found<<
it tries to reach www.example.com/be-fr/nid but the according node lies under www.example.com/en/nid even tough the language setting at the node itself is clear on be-fr.

so the question is how drupal constructes its path. what hooks are there we can look into to find the problem?

hope someone can help us, any clue appreciated!

Comment: I think it depends on how "Detection and Selection" settings are configured under Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Languages. Have you enabled URL detection ? Is it on top of the list ?

Comment: thx for the hint, but it's on top of the list and the only enabled item next to the default language at the bottom